# Abraham’s 3 visitors’ Knowledge

Tags: genesis, abraham

Gn 18:1-33

Gn 18:1-15
Twice in a few verses Sarah hears “about this time next year” she’ll have a son.  She first overhears the talking visitor tell Abraham that, and she laughs to herself at the possibility.  The Lord confronts her about laughing; she becomes afraid and lies that she ever did.  Meanwhile the Lord tells her what she already overheard (i.e. “about this time next year”).

Q#1: How and when did the trinity of visitors ever find out Sarah would be having a son?

Gn 18:16-33 "The men set out from there and looked down toward Sodom; Abraham was walking with them, to see them on their way”.  ...“While the 2 men walked on farther toward Sodom, the Lord remained standing before Abraham” and He and Abraham talked.  ..."The Lord departed as soon as He had finished speaking with Abraham, and Abraham returned home."

Q#2's: If we had 3 visitors and the Lord seeing Abraham, only 2 men walked farther toward Sodom, the Lord departed after speaking with Abraham, and Abraham went home, how can we account for a third  visitor?  Where did he go?  Did he get lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q#1: How and when did the trinity of visitors ever find out Sarah would be having a son?

Gen 18:1, Then the Lord appeared to him by the terebinth trees of Mamre

 God was among the visitors, or at least represented by the visitors.

> Q#2's: If we had 3 visitors and the Lord seeing Abraham, only 2 men walked farther toward Sodom, the Lord departed after speaking with Abraham, and Abraham went home, how can we account for a third visitor? Where did he go? Did he get lost?

Gen 8:16, Then the men rose from there and looked toward Sodom, and Abraham went with them to send them on the way.

Gen 19:1, Now the two angels came to Sodom in the evening

 Thus two men left, and they were angels.  3-2=1.  One was left.  This one spoke to Abraham, and was, or represented, God.  This is far from the only time a physical being is referred to as God/LORD in the Old Testament, cf. references to "the angel of the Lord".